# HP-UFT configure settings for capturing of Object Repository

Tags: hp-uft

Is it possible to customize/configure the Capture features in HP UFT Repository manager (Tools: "Navigate and Learn", "Spy" and "Add").

When capturing the object I would like to define what HP automatically sets as the name and test object properties.

For instance if property Help Text if available for an object, set this to the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way UFT determines what name to give an object is controlled by the `tag query name` in the registry.

The default value is **logical name** but you can change it to any other property supported by the object's `GetROProperty`.

In order to configure open `regedit` and go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mercury Interactive\QuickTest Professional\MicTest\TestObjects`.

Then under the object you want (e.g. `Edit`) change `tag query name` from **logical name** to the property you want (e.g. **placeholder**).

If the object in question is web-based and the property you want isn't supported by UFT you can use the [`attribute/` notation](https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing/QTP-identifying-custom-HTML-attributes/td-p/381135)

Comment: Thanks Motti. strange choice by HP for maintaining this information.

Comment: Please be advised that I'm not sure this is documented, it may just be an implementation detail and in that case it may change in future versions of UFT without notice.

Answer (score 0):

UFT has a 'Tools' > 'Object Identification'. Choose the object to modify, then add the property to the 'assistive' list.